# Having trouble with bool Book::isEmpty() const

Tags: c++, boolean

I am having trouble getting the correct output for my assignment.

**MY CODES:**

The Book.h

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

namespace sict {
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 16
#define MAX_TITLE_SIZE 32
#define MIN_ISBN_VALUE 1000000000000
#define MAX_ISBN_VALUE 9999999999999

class Book {
char m_authorfamilyname[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
char m_authorgivenname[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
char m_title[MAX_TITLE_SIZE];
unsigned long long m_ISBN;

public:
void set(const char authorfamilyname[], const char authorgivenname[], const char title[], unsigned long long ISBN );
void display() const;
bool isEmpty() const;
 };
}
#endif
```

The Book.cpp

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "Book.h
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

namespace sict {

void Book::set(const char authorfamilyname[], const char authorgivenname[], const char title[], unsigned long long ISBN)

m_authorfamilyname[0] = '\0';
m_authorgivenname[0] = '\0';
m_title[0] = '\0';
m_ISBN = 0;

strcpy(m_authorfamilyname, authorfamilyname);
strcpy(m_authorgivenname, authorgivenname);
strcpy(m_title, title);

m_ISBN = ISBN;
}

void Book::display() const {
if (isEmpty() && m_authorfamilyname[0] != '\0' && m_authorgivenname[0] != '\0' && m_title[0] != '\0' &&
m_ISBN >= MIN_ISBN_VALUE && m_ISBN <= MAX_ISBN_VALUE) {
cout << "Author: " << m_authorgivenname << ", " << m_authorfamilyname << endl;
cout << "Title: " << m_title << endl;
cout << "ISBN-13: " << m_ISBN << endl;
}
else {
cout << "The book object is empty!" << endl;
 }
}

bool Book::isEmpty() const {
bool Empty;
Empty = true;
return Empty;
```

And the main source file from my school

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Book.h"
#include "Book.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sict;

int main()
{
cout << "Book Management App" << endl;
cout << "===================" << endl;

Book aBook;

cout << "Testing that validation and display are correct:" << endl;
cout << "------------------------------------------------" << endl;
aBook.set("Frank", "Herbert", "Dune", 91780441172719LL);
aBook.display();
cout << "The Book::isEmpty() should return true --> "
<< (aBook.isEmpty() ? "correct" : "incorrect") << endl;

aBook.set("Frank", "Herbert", "Dune", 980441172719LL);
aBook.display();
cout << "The Book::isEmpty() should return true --> "
<< (aBook.isEmpty() ? "correct" : "incorrect") << endl;

aBook.set("Frank", "Herbert", "Dune", 9780441172719LL);
aBook.display();
cout << "The Book::isEmpty() should return false --> "
<< (aBook.isEmpty() ? "incorrect" : "correct") << endl;

return 0;
}
```

**The OUTPUT:**

```
The book object is empty!
The Book::isEmpty() should return true --> correct
The book object is empty!
The Book::isEmpty() should return true --> correct
Author: Herbert, Frank
Title: Dune
ISBN-13: 9780441172719
The Book::isEmpty() should return false --> *incorrect*<= the problem
```

The last line of the output should be 'correct' instead of 'incorrect'.

Is there any way to separate the last line to be 'correct'?

I tried if else and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably errors here that we can't see because this isn't all of the code. What I suggest, if you are going to use C++, is that you look into `std::string` and get rid of the C-style `const char[]`. From what we can see, you are copying the input into uninitialized memory, and the fact your program doesn't crash is probably just luck. And to the extent it makes sense, your isEmpty seems backwards. You would want `!isEmpty()`

Comment: Yes, use strings, commit to C++ totally. Otherwise you'll forever be known as a C+ coder, that strange purgatory between the C and C++ worlds :-)